# div/0 average error when there is not any empty cells and cells contains float numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, runtime-error, average, divide-by-zero

I want to have average for some float type cells and I don't have any empty cells. But when I use average formula it shows a div/0 error. 
I have changed the format of cells to number but it does not work.

screen shot :
[image: screen shot]

average cell format :
[image: average cell format]

Comment: Please show what you have done, probably a screenshot in this case.

Comment: there is an screenshot attached

Comment: Please also clarify the full expression you're using in the average cell.

Comment: there is an other screenshot

Answer (score 0):

For your system / numbers is a "." the decimal separator or ","? This could be causing your error.

Comment: I changed the decimal separator to "." but it does not changed.

Comment: Have you tried using SUM() or MAX() on the same range of numbers? i only ask as if they are not accepted as numbers then the functions won't work - I entered your numbers onto a sheet of mine and the average works so there must be something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it. With right clicking on the error and selecting "convert to number" the format will be changed and so the average result will be shown